# how to change specific field in realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to change review field.

[image: Database Structure]

I managed only to create new item in road db wth this code:

```
mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

     //    DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Road");
     //   ref.child("review").setValue(rating).toString();


 }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this but do note that you need to know the Road ID:

```
mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        Map<String, Object> reviewUpdate = new HashMap<>();
        reviewUpdate.put("/Road/" + roadId + "/review/", "NewReviewValue");

        mDatabase.updateChildren(reviewUpdate);  
    }
});
```

Similarly you can update other fields using `reviewUpdate.put()`

Comment: Thank you! It helped so much, corrected a bit to get to review: `reviewUpdate.put("/Road/" + roadId + "/review/", "NewReviewValue");` Thanks again!